# How to loop through files matching wildcard in batch file

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, batch-file

I have a set of base filenames, for each name 'f' there are exactly two files, 'f.in' and 'f.out'.  I want to write a batch file (in Windows XP) which goes through all the filenames, for each one it should:

- Display the base name 'f'
- Perform an action on 'f.in'
- Perform another action on 'f.out'

I don't have any way to list the set of base filenames, other than to search for *.in (or *.out) for example.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Assuming you have two programs that process the two files, process_in.exe and process_out.exe:

```
for %%f in (*.in) do (
    echo %%~nf
    process_in "%%~nf.in"
    process_out "%%~nf.out"
)
```

%%~nf is a substitution modifier, that expands %f to a file name only.
See other modifiers in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx (midway down the page) or just in the next answer.

Comment: Use a single '%' if typing this on the command line.  I know the OP doesn't ask about the command line, but that's what I was searching for when this question came up at the top of my Google search.  Others may appreciate this bit.

Comment: Could you explain the syntax? The loop variable is declared `%%f` why is it `%%~nf` later?

Comment: @ColonelPanic - there are a handful of `~` modifiers to do things, like in my example, just get the filename. It's just habit for me to use that in case the `*` does the full path or something. There are a handful of these modifiers (midway down the page): http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: what if the file and the directory have spaces in them?

Comment: Also, be aware that the %%f variable must be a single letter - cryptic error messages will appear if you try to use something readable and meaningful.

Answer (score 108):

You can use this line to print the contents of your desktop:

```
FOR %%I in (C:\windows\desktop\*.*) DO echo %%I
```

Once you have the `%%I` variable it's easy to perform a command on it (just replace the word echo with your program)

In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced
You can now use the following optional syntax:

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only (directory with \)
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
%~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable and expands %I to the
               fully qualified name of the first one found.
               If the environment variable name is not
               defined or the file is not found by the
               search, then this modifier expands to the
               empty string
```

https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

In the above examples `%I` and PATH can be replaced by other valid
values.  The `%~` syntax is terminated by a valid FOR variable name.
Picking upper case variable names like `%I` makes it more readable and
avoids confusion with the modifiers, which are not case sensitive.

You can get the full documentation by typing `FOR /?`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  `%%I was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: @Brad if you're using this in the command-line (and not in a batch file), then use `%I` instead of `%%I`

Comment: A much better answer than the accepted. All flags/modifiers included within the answer and not a third party website (_nobody wants to click your link, Louis_)

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way, as I see it, is to use a for loop that calls a second batch file for processing, passing that second file the base name.

According to the for /? help, basename can be extracted using the nifty ~n option. So, the base script would read:

```
for %%f in (*.in) do call process.cmd %%~nf
```

Then, in process.cmd, assume that %0 contains the base name and act accordingly. For example:

```
echo The file is %0
copy %0.in %0.out
ren %0.out monkeys_are_cool.txt
```

There might be a better  way to do this in one script, but I've always been a bit hazy on how to pull of multiple commands in a single for loop in a batch file.

EDIT: That's fantastic! I had somehow missed the page in the docs that showed that you could do multi-line blocks in a FOR loop. I am going to go have to go back and rewrite some batch files now...

Comment: %0 in process.cmd looks to contain process.cmd itself. It appears %1 should be used in process.cmd instead.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [Nathans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142/nathan-fritz) post. The following will do the job lot in one batch file.

```
@echo off

if %1.==Sub. goto %2

for %%f in (*.in) do call %0 Sub action %%~nf
goto end

:action
echo The file is %3
copy %3.in %3.out
ren %3.out monkeys_are_cool.txt

:end
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool usually used in MS Servers (as far as I can remember) called [forfiles](http://www.ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html):

The link above contains help as well as a link to the microsoft download page.

Answer (score 2):

The code below filters filenames starting with given substring. It could be changed to fit different needs by working on subfname substring extraction and IF statement:

```
echo off
rem filter all files not starting with the prefix 'dat'
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /R your-folder-fullpath %%F IN (*.*) DO (
set fname=%%~nF
set subfname=!fname:~0,3!
IF NOT "!subfname!" == "dat" echo "%%F"
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Echoing f.in and f.out will seperate the concept of what to loop and what not to loop when used in a for /f loop.

```
::Get the files seperated
echo f.in>files_to_pass_through.txt
echo f.out>>files_to_pass_through.txt

for /F %%a in (files_to_pass_through.txt) do (
for /R %%b in (*.*) do (
if "%%a" NEQ "%%b" (
echo %%b>>dont_pass_through_these.txt
)
)
)
::I'm assuming the base name is the whole string "f".
::If I'm right then all the files begin with "f".
::So all you have to do is display "f". right?
::But that would be too easy.
::Let's do this the right way.
for /f %%C in (dont_pass_through_these.txt)
::displays the filename and not the extention
echo %~nC
)
```

Although you didn't ask, a good way to pass commands into f.in and f.out would be to...

```
for /F %%D "tokens=*" in (dont_pass_through_these.txt) do (
for /F %%E in (%%D) do (
start /wait %%E
)
)
```

A link to all the Windows XP commands:[link](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true)

I apologize if I did not answer this correctly. The question was very hard for me to read.