# Creating a batch file to do drag and drop files onto an exe

Tags: batch-file

I have an exe that I can drag and drop another file onto to produce a third file. Unfortunately it seems to accept only 1 file at a time, if I select multiple and drop it doesn't seem to work.

How do I create a batch file to automate the process of dragging a thousand files of .drag extension onto drop.exe?

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't it  be MS-DOS?

Comment: DOS had no drag & drop. You mean Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows, dropping a file on an exe just executes the command line:

```
fileprocessor.exe "<full path to dropped file>"
```

So you should be able to just call the exe directly in your batch file, passing the path to each file that you'd like to process.

EDIT: Look into the For batch command to do this for a series of files. You should be able to specify the wildcard and then call the command for each.

```
For %%a in (*.drag) do fileprocessor.exe "%%~fa"
```

Comment: oh wow I do not want to write 1000 paths. shouldn't I be able to do a wildcard? Such as all .drag files in this folder?

Answer (score 2):

Evidently, batch files can have multiple objects dropped onto them.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243240/drag-and-drop-batch-file-for-multiple-files).  You should be able to adapt the answer to your needs.  I do wonder if there is a maximum number of characters that can be passed in, though, so you might not be able to drag *thousands* of files onto it.  Possibly not even hundreds.  But definitely multiple.

EDIT: In your comment to dmercredi's answer, you mention wildcards.  If you don't need the drag/drop capability and just want to specify *.drag in your batch file, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file) instead.  There are a variety of answers there that may suit your needs.

Comment: There is a maximum command-line length for cmd. 8191 characters.