# How to decode multiple file with wildcard in Windows commandline

Tags: windows, file, command-line-interface

I have the (console) program `flac.exe` and I want to be able to decode all `flac` files to `wav` in one directory, without have to do each one at a time.

I tried:

```
flac -d *.flac
```

But it errors out trying to create the wav file.

Comment: Those smarter than I have already answered for you.

http://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this on the commandline:

```
for %i in (*.flac) do flac %i
```

If you want to put that into a batch file, you have to use `%%i` instead of `%i`

Comment: this works! also i tried decoding in bash shell it it works like i wrote it above.
    `flac -d *.flac`

i had to modify your dos code cause i forgot to include the decode option and the flac files had symbols in their names.
   `for %i in (*.flac) do flac -d "%i"`

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [this bulk rename](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Command.php) utility?

*Bulk Rename Utility is an easy to use file rename program (a.k.a. file renamer). Renaming multiple files has never been easier! It has a small memory footprint so it can be left running all the time without consuming all your memory. It started as a freeware Visual Basic tool, but as its popularity has grown it has been completely rewritten in C++ to be robust and lightweight - and very, very fast! It can easily handle folders/discs containing well over 100,000 entries... and it can batch rename 1,000s of files in seconds.*

Comment: I don't see any requirement to rename files in the question.