# perl replace multi files in. a folder

Tags: perl, wildcard

This works

```
Perl -pi.bak -e "s/\\t/\t/g;" one.xml
```

But this doesnt work for all xmls in the folder

```
Perl -pi.bak -e "s/\\t/\t/g;" *.xml
```

Keep getting error `cannot open *.xml`

Have tried all sorts of things and recognise the `*` as a wildcard

Comment: Let me guess, are you working on Windows?

Comment: Yes running the command on the windows command line from within the folder where the xmls are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the `cannot open *.xml` because, unlike Unix shells, the Windows CMD shell does not expand wild cards.

If you want to stay with `cmd`, you can form a [`for` loop over files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file) or you could switch to something more powerful like PowerShell and try this (untested): `Perl -pi.bak -e "s/\\t/\t/g;" (Get-ChildItem *.xml | % { "$_" })`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, windows cmd does not have the same power to expand wildcards as unix shells.

You can work around this though, by telling perl that you want to expand `@ARGV` using a [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

```
perl -i.bak -pe "BEGIN {@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV} s/\\t/\t/g;" *.xml
```