# for statement/file processing in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Using this as am example
[For statement in batch script from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file)

tried the following

```
for %%f in (c:\username\desktop\Test\*.log) do (
    echo %%~nf
)
```

I get the following error: `%%f was unexpected at this time`

My goal is to move [n] files from one dir to another, wait [x] seconds and then move the next [n] files

I can do the time wait by doing a ping for an unknown site and force the delay or use timeout [not yet tested as this would need to be done without any user intervention]

If there is a better way to do this, i am open as this is my first dab at this type of scripting.

Comment: Your problem "%%f was unexpected..." is caused by attempting to execute a batch command directly from the prompt.You need to save the text in a file named somethingorother.bat - the *.bat* being the key. You then execute *somethingorother.bat* by entering *somethingorother* at the prompt; the **.bat** file is then selected and run. Certainly easier than perpetually re-typing the command line. If you expressly want to run directly from the prompt, reduce any `%%x` in a *metavariable* (the loop-control variable) to `%x`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::The number of files to copy
set [n]=10
::The time to wait after copying [n] files
set $tempo=5
::Your source path
set $sourceDir="C:\your\source\path"
::Your destination path
set $DestDir="C:\your\destination\path"

set $c=1
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b/a-d %$SourceDir% *.log') do (
    if !$c! equ %[n]% (
        timeout %$tempo%
        set $c=1
    )
    copy "%$SourceDir:~1,-1%\%%~nxf" %$Destdir%
    set /a $c+=1
)
echo Done...
```

Assuming that the extension to test is `.log`.  If not you have to change it.

Comment: I tried the suggestion, however it picks up non *.log files as well.