# run python script in every file in a directory through command line

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, windows-shell

I have a python script which takes the filename as a command argument and processes that file. However, i have thousands of files I need to process, and I would like to run the script on every file without having to add the filename as the argument each time.

for example: 
`process.py file1` will do exactly what I want

however, I want to run process.py on a folder containing thousands of files (file1, file2, file3, etc.)

I have found out it that it can be done simply in Bash

```
for f in *; do python myscript.py $f; done
```

However, I am on windows and don't want to install something like Cygwin.
What would a piece of code for the Windows command line look like that would emulate what the above Bash code accomplishes?

Comment: Do you want a solution that is purely Python (i.e. done inside your Python script) or one that utilizes Windows batch abilities?

Comment: BTW, in bash it is better to use `python myscript.py "$f"`, otherwise it would break if there was a space in a filename.

Comment: I am open to solutions that work either way. Ideally, it would be done within the python script, and then I could pass an argument for the folder location to process when I run the python script. However, if it is easier done with windows batch that is fine

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%f in (*.py) do (
    start %%f
)
```

I think that'll work -- I don't have a Windows box handy at the moment to try it

[How to loop through files matching wildcard in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file)

That link might help

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, subprocess
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        subprocess.call(["python", "myscript.py", f])
```

this solution will work on every platform, provided the python executable is in the PATH.

Also, if you want to recursively process files in nested subdirectories, you can use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.walk) instead of [`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir)+[`os.path.isfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=isfile#os.path.isfile).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have python, why not use that?

```
import subprocess
import glob
import sys
import os.path

for fname in glob.iglob(os.path.join('some-directory-name','*')):
    proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'myscript.py', fname])
    proc.wait()
```

What's more, its portable.

Comment: this looks good, but isn't working for me. I replaced the 'some-directory-name' with an absolute reference to the folder containing the files, and 'myscript.py' with an absolute reference to the script I want to run. However, when I run the code it seems to freeze up and slow down my computer without ever giving me the output it is supposed to. Am I missing something? I'm attempting to run the code in iPython QTConsole

Comment: Sounds like it is working!  If you have thousands of files then you are gong to get thousands of child processes.  I don't know your environment, there could be a buffering issue explaining the lack of output - IDLE, for example, will not display output from a child process.  I suggest you test this with a small number of files (say around 5) to prove the principle.  Really your design of running a child process for every file is suspect.  In reality the python script should be altered to access the files, rather than running them like this.

Answer (score 0):

For each file in current dir.

```
for %f in (*) do C:\Python34\python.exe "%f"
```

**Update:**
Note the quotes on the **%f**. You need them if your files contain spaces in the name. You can also put any path+executable after the **do**.

If we imagine your files look like:

./**process.py**

./myScripts/**file1.py**

./myScripts/**file2.py**

./myScripts/**file3.py**

...

In your example, would simply be:

```
for %f in (.\myScripts\*) do process.py "%f"
```

This would invoke:

```
process.py ".\myScripts\file1.py"
process.py ".\myScripts\file2.py"
process.py ".\myScripts\file3.py"
```

Comment: how would I reference my python script with this construction?