# Looping through a directory in DOS and performing a command on them

Tags: loops, pdf, command, dos

I have a folder of PDF documents that I want to strip the first page off.
I have found a tool that does this from the command line and this works successfully.
This is the command that I am using:

```
pdftk 1.pdf cat 2- output 1_Stripped.pdf
```

where `1.pdf` is the original filename, and I have `1_Stripped.pdf` as the output file.

It will take me forever to do this for each file, I'm sure that within DOS there must be a way of looping around every file in the directory and doing that command for them.  (Passing in the filename automatically and then having the output as having "_Stripped" at the end.  But I'm struggling to do it.

I thought that this would do the trick:

```
for file in *.pdf 
    pdftk "$file" cat 2- output "$file"stripped;
done
```

but I'm just getting error messages.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post and add the error messages you are getting?

Comment: Here is an older question that has been answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved now, with this FOR %i IN (*.pdf) DO pdftk %i cat 2-end output "stripped/"%i"_stripped.pdf"