# Windows command prompt loop syntax for running a exe to batch convert images jpegs

Tags: windows, loops, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I'm using the following  [directXtex texconv](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texconv) command to convert textures individually

```
texconv -pow2 -f BC1_UNORM cat.jpg
```

However I'd like to convert a whole folder full of textures. I'm told I need to loop through all textures feeding them in to texconv.exe. How can I do this in the Windows command prompt?

There are other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file) to this, however this answer can be run within the command prompt, whereas my question is likely to require an external batch file - possibly because it is dealing with jpeg files. I don't know how to set this up

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop through files matching wildcard in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file)

Comment: The context is different, and as such I can't see how it applies to my question: There using two files on an in and out exe whereas I have one exe and 100s of textures

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood what the suggested solution to the question I linked to does. It iterates over all files with a certain file ending, and executes a program for each such file. The fact that it also executes another program for a file with the same name but a different file ending is irrelevant, and something you can just ignore.

Comment: so how exactly do i adapt `for %%f in (*.in) do (

            echo %%~nf
            process_in "%%~nf.in"
            process_out "%%~nf.out"
    )` to be used to process my images using **texconv.exe**? Im guessing I need to replace: *1* `*.in` with `*.jpg` ? *2* `process_in` with `texconv`. *However* I cant work out what to replace `%%f in` with - is this just a variable or referencing to  `f.in` which in *my case is different?* Im a newby, thanks for your patience

Comment: `%%f` would be the name of the current jpg file. So `texconv -pow2 -f BC1_UNORM %%f` should do, if you want to use the same options for every file.

Comment: `for texconv -pow2 -f BC1_UNORM %%f in (*.jpg) do (

            echo %%~nf
            texconv "%%~nf.in"
    )` produces [texconv was unexpected at this time](http://i.imgur.com/lU6ykc9.jpg)

Comment: `for %%f in (*.in) do ( texconv -pow2 -f BC1_UNORM %%f )`

Comment: pasting your code in the CMD produces "%%f was unexpected at this time."?

Comment: Put it in a .bat file instead (and obviously `*.in` should've been `*.jpg`).

Comment: that worked [very nicely indeed](http://i.imgur.com/tgBcBZK.jpg) thank you very much. Perhaps my initial question wasn't as comprehensive as it could of been, i can edit it to highlight the fact we had to use a .bat file and other things? Then you can put your comments as an answer and i can tick off for you?