# Choose Random text file in batch

Tags: batch-file

is it possible to make a batch file choose a totally random text file from within a specified folder

and can somebody help me make it?

example
lets say that i got a folder located here: C:\Workstation\Jobs
and in that folder there is maybe 10-20 .txt files at a time

the goal here is to make that batch file check the folder and then choose a random file and output the choosen file to a variable

Comment: You're going to want to reword your question, because right now the answer is "yes, it is."

Comment: are there other files in the said folder?

Comment: @YVbakker no there will only be text files

Comment: Oh geez, I didn't mean reword it like _that_. Now it's too broad. If you have code, please add it to your question. If you don't have any code, write some and then add it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt"^|find /i /c ".txt" '
 ) DO SET /a selection=1 + (%RANDOM% %% %%a)
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt"^|findstr /n /i ".txt" '
 ) DO IF %%a==%selection% SET filename=%%b
ECHO selected %filename%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

`find /c` counts the number of files found by the `dir` command and the `for` assigns the count to `%%a`. `selection` is then assigned to 1+(*randomnumber* mod *filecount*) giving 1..filecount.

`findstr /n` outputs the name of each file found by the `dir` command, prefixed by *a sequential number* :   %%a will be assigned the number (token before the `:` and `%%b` the filename (afther the first delimiter where delims is `:`)

When the line number matches `selection`, filename is assigned the filename found.

Comment: there is only one problem with your code. it doesnt seem to handle files with spaces that well, by that i mean it complete refuses to run

Comment: Runs perfectly for me, even with spaces in the filenames or with spaces in the directoryname. Please post a small sample of the filenames you are using and are giving trouble.

Comment: the file names are  actually usernames for the pc which made the work so: Private User Account.txt, Guest User Account.txt, Dave's Account.txt, Lennys Account.txt

Comment: Works perfectly for me with those filenames. Try changing `DO SET /a selection...` to `DO echo%%a&SET /a selection...` which should report the number of .txt files found to the screen. If it reports 0, then there's something wrong with the `dir` or `find` statement. Try copying the `dir` statement (just the `dir` part - up to but not including the `^`) onto a line before the first `for`. This should list the filenames. I hope you haven't tried to retype the code - you should copy-and-paste. A single character out of place can cause strange results.

Comment: it lists the files no proplem

Comment: ...and what filecount did it display?

Comment: the echo displayed 17 even though it was hard to notice becouse it closed instantly

Comment: Add a pause statement directly before the `goto :eof`. This will hold the window open until you press `enter`. If you place a line `echo on` before the second `for/f` then you should get a trace of exactly the commands being executed. Since I can't see what you are *actually* doing with the value in `filename` I'd suggest you try surrounding `%filename%` with quotes thus: `"%filename%"` - quoting filenames ensures the string between the quotes is interpreted as a single unit.

Comment: idk what the problem was but i closed notepad++ and started it again and now it runs.. :/

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the said folder only containing text files, you'd need the following:

- a list of folder contents in some sort of array (dir)
- count the amount of files (for loop)
- pick a random number between 0 and the amount of files (%RANDOM%*amount_of_files/32768)
- output the matching filename (in the array) to the variable you want

Hope this pushes you in the right direction :-)

sources:
http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html
[How to loop through files matching wildcard in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file)
[Create list or arrays in Windows Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-list-or-arrays-in-windows-batch)