# How to write a script for multiple files and apply java class?

Tags: batch-file

I'll do my best explain what I'm trying to do here. I'm new to writing scripts and need to write a script. That allows me to create bunch of output files with Java class appending to it?

Here my batch script that I'm working on and this command works with a single file in the directory. When I enter *@pxp_local for input filename and test.txt for output filename

```
Java ClassTest <input filename> <output filename>
```

But I need to process multiple files that contains @pxp_local in filename in the directory. Then create an output filename for all @pxp_local files with a counter while also applying the Java ClassTest class.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to loop over a set of files in your script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file

Comment: Here's my script that I have created but it doesn't seem to be applying to series of files. Is there a command I'm missing that my prevent to applying to multiple of files with the name of *@npipvwbm03_ppx_local and with output of "%date:/=-% %time::=-%.edi"??

@echo off

set loop = 0
:loop

java aPxmlToDoc *@npipvwbm03_ppx_local "%date:/=-% %time::=-%.edi"

timeout /t 5

set /a loop=%loop%+1 
if "%loop%" == "5" goto end
goto loop
:end