# Batch script to rename PDF files using the content

Tags: batch-file, pdf

I have a batch script used to extract PDF information and rename the PDF then.

The script is working fine for 1 PDF file but I need to use it directly in a **folder** with a lot of PDF files.

So how to do it?

The script needs to run for each PDF file, one by one until the end.
Once the PDF file is renamed next the file is moved in another folder, so the PDF file remaining in the folder need the same thing. And when the folder is empty the script exits.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set PDF="Renommer_Manuellement.pdf"
set text="Renommer_Manuellement.txt"
set DSUBDIX=%USERPROFILE%\Google Drive\CLASSEURS

ren *.pdf %PDF%
pdftotext -raw %PDF%

for /f "delims=- tokens=2" %%a in ('find "Number=" %text%') do set numeroa=%%a

for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%a in ('find "NAME=" %text%') do set nature=%%a


ren "%PDF%" "OCC-%numeroa:~0,5%#!nature!.pdf"
move "%PDF%" "OCC-%numeroa:~0,5%#!nature!.pdf" "XYZ FOLDER"

exit
```

Comment: this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this commented batch file code works for moving all PDF files in current directory to subdirectory `XYZ FOLDER` with new file name determined from contents of each PDF file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Don't know what this environment variable is for. It is not used by this code.
set "DSUBDIX=%USERPROFILE%\Google Drive\CLASSEURS"

md "XYZ FOLDER" 2>nul

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir *.pdf /A-D /B 2^>nul') do call :RenamePDF "%%~fI"

rem Restore initial command environment and exit batch file processing.
endlocal
goto :EOF


:RenamePDF
set "FilePDF=%~1"
set "FileTXT=%~dpn1.txt"

pdftotext.exe -raw "%FilePDF%"

for /F "delims=- tokens=2" %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "Number=" "%FileTXT%"') do set "numeroa=%%J"
for /F "delims== tokens=2" %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "NAME=" "%FileTXT%"') do set "nature=%%J"

rem The text version of the PDF file is no longer needed.
del "%FileTXT%"

rem Move the PDF file to XYZ FOLDER and rename the file while moving it.
move "%FilePDF%" "XYZ FOLDER\OCC-%numeroa:~0,5%#%nature%.pdf"

rem The file movement could fail in case of a PDF file with new
rem name exists already in target folder. In this case rename
rem the PDF file in its current folder.
if errorlevel 1 ren "%FilePDF%" "OCC-%numeroa:~0,5%#%nature%.pdf"

rem Exit the subroutine RenamePDF and continue with FOR loop in main code.
goto :EOF
```

It is unclear for me why each *.pdf file should be moved into a subdirectory with new file name.
This is not really necessary in my point of view. The command **REN** could be enough.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `rem /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

See also [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)