# How to sort .pdf based on their content using CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I have like 200 PDF documents that will be saved in a folder (every day), I have to sort them based on a their content. (All pdf-documents have the string "`X_P1`" or "`X_P2`" in it)

My first step is to convert the `.pdf` file to `a.txt` files using `XPDF`:

```
for /r %%i in (*pdf) do "C:\Users\xxx\pdftotext.exe" -layout "%%i"
```

So I end up with 200 PDF files and 200 text files in a folder.

Looks like this:

> p100.pdf 
>   p100.txt 
>   p101.pdf 
>   p101.txt 
>   ...

So for the next step I thought of searching for the string "`X_P1`" in the `.txt` file with `FINDSTR` and save the filename as a variable. (e.g. `p100`) Next step: Move all files that name is the same as the variabel to a folder.

I'm not very familiar with batch/powershell so how can I work with the result from `FINDSTR`. I thought of maybe using the `errorlevels`? So if I get `ERORRLEVEL 0` move to folder 1 .

Comment: Is **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48249134)** not a possible duplicate?

Comment: janikoo5, I have rolled back your previous two edits. Please do not change your question into an answer, use the answer area and post your solution there!

Comment: It is a possible duplicate.

Comment: No apology necessary @somebadhat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(All pdf-documents have the string "X_P1" or "X_P2" in it)**

Sort them based on their content.

Convert a .pdf to text.  If you find "X_P1" move to `xp1` if not move to `xp2`.

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
REM begin debug 
REM del "%userprofile%\Desktop\*.pdf" 2>nul 
REM rd /q /s xp1 2>nul 
REM rd /q /s xp2 2>nul
REM copy /y "%userprofile%\Desktop\New Folder\*.pdf" "%userprofile%\Desktop\" 1>nul
REM   end debug
md xp1 2>nul
md xp2 2>nul
for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
pdftotext.exe -raw %%a tmp.txt
find "X_P1" tmp.txt > nul && move %%a xp1 || move %%a xp2
)
del tmp.txt
exit /b
```