# Windows BATCH filter with regex

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I need to do a bat script to process file one by one, according to a number in the filename. Here is an example of what I can get :

1. CDEP_0003.pdf
2. CIM_0001.pdf
3. ESCALE_0002.pdf

It's possible to loop and process each of those files in an ordered way using regex or something like this to exclude the number and use it as a loop index ? (0001, 0002, 0003 etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop through `.*0000\.pdf$` to `.*9999\.pdf$` using another answer on [how to loop through files matching wildcard in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 1):

You could

- build an array of used numbers by first iterating through the files, or
- use a counting loop (`for /l`) from 10000 to 19999 to have the
  leading zeros and take the last 4 digits..

Provided there is only one underscore preceding the number:

```
@Echo off
Pushd "X:\folder\to\start"
::clear array
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('Set No[ 2^>Nul') do Set "%%A=" 
:: fill array
for /f "tokens=2delims=_." %%A in (
    'Dir /B "*_????.pdf" ^| findstr "^.*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.pdf$"'
) Do Set /A "No[%%A]=%%A"
:: process existing numbers
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%A in ('Set No[ 2^>Nul') do (
   Rem dir "*_%%A.pdf" or whatever you want to do
)
```